# How are the hashes in tumblr image urls generated?

Tags: hash, tumblr

Disclaimer: hobbyist here, not a professional programmer. Working on a pet project, nothing that would be useful in the real world.

I'm trying to determine whether the hashes in the url of a tumblr image are in any way related to the contents of the image itself. A typical url looks like this:

```
media.tumblr.com/3b675b5cdc9c6f9414626ba7e0c62f96/tumblr_n8949eWEIi1rw1wnno1_400.gif
```

As you can see, there's a 32-character hash and another 19-character hash. I've tried all of the hashing algorithms supported by PHP 5.4.24, but none of them produces either of these codes. I've looked at the useless tumblr api, and done some searching around, but I can't find anything about how these codes are generated. Does anyone outside of tumblr know?

Comment: I am not 100% sure they use PHP for hashes: http://www.quora.com/Tumblr/What-is-Tumblrs-technology-stack Sadly it seems its a big secret, wish I could be more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that it's just a hash of the content, people upload duplicates all the time and it has to result in a different url. They are likely randomly generated numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into this right now.

According to this [Image URL Naming Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919766/image-url-naming-scheme) the "path hash" is generated from the sha1sum of the original uploaded file (not the resized _1280 one).

`URL | Post ID
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_o52i3aUCp21s6b18b_raw.png    142356364280
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_o5p15wTJvV1s6b18b_raw.png    142862598358
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_o6krbiugVC1t8vyl1_raw.png    143764052781
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_o8b40w7wGg1t8vyl1_raw.png    145458898886
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_o8ze2tfKNF1t8vyl1_raw.png    146118662296
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_odemy29NAE1tnns90_raw.png    150330941101
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_oeca19dxFg1t8vyl1_raw.png    151163621951
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_oefltuWf7l1t8vyl1_raw.png    151247611726
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_ofvlu8QK0T1sjl8et_raw.png    152521367261
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_oio5kwLNvv1t8vyl1_raw.png    154875513091
https://data.tumblr.com/20b42c7d2d3613dbd9450b5a506cfbd3/tumblr_inline_p1brk7DTpU1tdsqfw_raw.png    168794714560`

the Post ID is what you get in a typical [tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#common-fields) response.

Another proof that the original file's content is used for generation:
`https://data.tumblr.com/20aa2775a98061db21f6f86ad46df399/tumblr_noafrk8hB41uowduuo1_r1_raw.png 118859314504
https://data.tumblr.com/20aa2775a98061db21f6f86ad46df399/tumblr_o87jds0wPW1uowduuo1_raw.png 145364317345`

The *r1* means revision number 1, the file has been altered by the original author, but the path hash and filename are kept the same.